# Installation of Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 fails - USB error, graphics error?

Tags: nvidia, system-installation, uefi, live-usb

I currently have Ubuntu 14.04 installed, but I want a fresh start. I am going to wipe the drive and install Ubuntu Gnome 16.04. Unfortunately I'm having no success at all.

I downloaded `ubuntu-gnome-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso` (the md5 checksum matches) and installed it to a new USB drive. My BIOS allows for both a Legacy Boot and a UEFI boot. I've posted the results when I drive to boot both as Legacy an UEFI below. I'm not sure how to solve these issues. I've tried a different USB drive, and different ports.

My video card is a NVIDIA Corporation GM204 [GeForce GTX 970].

Is this possibly a problem with the boot process, the USB, graphics drivers?

## Legacy boot results

I get the gfxboot.c32 error. I hit [Tab], then I tried live and live-install. Both result in this error

[image]

## UEFI Result

This is the screen that is produced. It flickers a bit, then just remains in the image I show here.

[image]

Comment: Try booting with `nomodeset` as described in https://askubuntu.com/a/162076

Comment: Thanks for the help. I set ```nomodeset``` and I made it further. But now it's giving a whole host of USB errors. Perhaps there something wrong with both of the USB drives I'm using. Is there a way to test the drive?

Comment: Not sure, maybe from a different computer? You could compare hashes of the USB drive and the ones provided for the Ubuntu isos. If you boot in UEFI mode (not sure about CSM), there should also be an option to verify the disk image. However, could you please add the exact errors you get now to your question?

Comment: I believe that something is broken on the motherboard. I have ordered a new one.

Comment: This is a common Nvidia issue.